# Cadence Virtuoso - Cell Parameterized

Tags: integrated-circuit, layout, cadence

Please see attached. I am unable to view the Poly, Metal, Cont layers for the PMOS & NMOS instances. Need a bit of assitance on how to fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you were trying to do, and perhaps typing out the error message so that future visitors would find your question more easily? Please don't reply in comments, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that under Options->Display there would be a way to choose number of layers. You can explore LSW a bit more.

1. There is a difference between selecting and displaying layers. If you are not sure, you can end up moving entire chunks of layout leaving contacts/or something else behind.
2. The error message on screen is obvious (You can't edit the layout of a pcell). You can always define your own cell and edit the copy.

Comment: https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/custom-ic-design/11754/how-to-display-a-p-cell-s-constituent-layers-in-a-layout-layout-xl-virtuoso-ic6-1-1